# Find a general solution to ODE $y'=f(Ax+By+C)$ with substitution $u=Ax+By+C$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If an ODE can be written as $y' = f(Ax+By+C)$, the substitution $u=Ax+By+C$ reduces the equation to a separable one.

Then, find the general solution to such an equation in terms of $y$ and $x$. Is it implicit or explicit?

---

If we differentiate $u=Ax+By+C$ wrt $x$:

$\frac{du}{dx}=A+B\frac{dy}{dx}$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{B}(\frac{du}{dx}-A)$

If we substitute this into $y'=f(Ax+By+C)$ we get

$f(u)=\frac{1}{B}(\frac{du}{dx}-A)$

$\frac{du}{dx}=Bf(u)+A$

Now if we integrate wrt $x$:

$$u=B \int f(u)dx +Ax+D$$

$$\implies Ax+By+C=B*\int f(Ax+By+C)dx + Ax +D$$

This is a general solution and it is implicit since we can't solve for a variable on one side.

Am I correct?

Comment: Note that you can just differentiate both sides with respect to $x$ which gives $$A + B y' = B f (Ax + By + C) + A \implies y' = f (Ax + By + C)$$ so yes, your solution is correct. An alternative expression, via separation of variables, would be $$\int \frac{du}{B f(u) + A} = x + D$$

Comment: How is this a solution? A solution gives you some way of determining what $y$ is. But this doesn't do so. It just switches a differential equation to an integral equation. But as $y$ occurs inside the integral, you have to already know it to perform the integration. The "alternate" expression Matthew Cassell gives is what they intended. There the integration is of a function of just $u$ with $u$ as the variable of integration. This gives $x$ as a function of $u$, which can be inverted to get $u$ (and therefore $y$) as a function of $x$.